# Wanting to know how to place a pinpoint marker to my lat, long using this code

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm trying to find a way to place a pinpoint marker to my lat, long on Google Maps.

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Nav10 extends MapActivity {
    MapController mControl;
    GeoPoint GeoP;
    MapView navView10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nav10);

        navView10 = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.navView10);
        navView10.displayZoomControls(true);
        navView10.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        navView10.setSatellite(true);

        double lat = 40.325874;
        double longi = -76.002211;

        GeoP = new GeoPoint((int) ( lat *1E6), (int) (longi * 1E6));

        mControl = navView10.getController();
        mControl.animateTo(GeoP);
        mControl.setZoom(20);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

How would I insert a pinpoint marker with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [MyLocationOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/index). You just need to add it to your mapView:

```
mapView.getOverlays().add(new MyLocationOverlay(context,mapView) );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! But is it possible if you can elaborate a little more. I'm a brand newbe. Maybe insert it into my code i provided. Also have another question. Do I need two java classes to do this? one with this code and another for the pinpoint marker?

Comment: Put below navView10.setSatellite(true):
navView10.getOverlays().add(new MyLocationOverlay(this,navView10));

Comment: Thanks again!!! I thought that's where i was to insert it, with navView10. But I'm still not getting anything. Do I need to do anything in the xml? If not thanks for the help again!!!