# placing a pinpoint marker to my Google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Ok I've asked this before. Got one answer. I'm going to go more in depth on what I'm doing. I'm creating a app for a business that has multiple stores. I have a layout that shows button to each store. click on one of the buttons it takes you to another view with two buttons on it. In this view theres a button that when u click it it calls the store for u, got that working just fine. the other button in the same view when u click it it takes you to Google maps and shows u where the location of the store is. This all works fine. But what i want is a marker to show up on the map as well. I don't need it to do anything but show the customer this is where the store is located. This is my code I'm using--->

```
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

import com.google.android.maps.MapController;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends MapActivity {

    MapController mControl;

    GeoPoint GeoP;

    MapView navView;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        navView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.navView);

        navView.displayZoomControls(true);

        navView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            navView.setSatellite(true);

            navView.getOverlays().add(new MyLocationOverlay(this,navView));




        double lat = 40.325874;

        double longi = -76.002211;

        GeoP = new GeoPoint((int) ( lat *1E6), (int) (longi * 1E6));

        mControl = navView.getController();

        mControl.animateTo(GeoP);

        mControl.setZoom(20);

        }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339759/wanting-to-know-how-to-place-a-pinpoint-marker-to-my-lat-long-using-this-code

Comment: Yea that's my post from earlier... I need a little more help... I tried that, if you see i have it in the code above. I've been searching for a answer all day on the internet. I'm getting and have no idea what to do or how to do this with this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Erik Graul

Check this tutorial , it will help you

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Answer (score 2):

check out this  [hhttp://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mapOverlayDemo.htm](http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/mapOverlayDemo.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY());
Drawable srcdrawable = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pin_blue);
CustomItemizedOverlay srcitemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(srcdrawable, getApplicationContext());
OverlayItem srcoverlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "Hello!", "This is your Location.");
srcitemizedOverlay.addOverlay(srcoverlayitem);
mapView.getOverlays().clear();
mapView.getOverlays().add(srcitemizedOverlay);
mapController.animateTo(srcpoint);
mapController.setZoom(16);
```

Use the above code in ontouch method also use the below CustomItemizedOverlay.java class

```
public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

    private final ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    private Context context;

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    }

    public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        this(defaultMarker);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return mapOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return mapOverlays.size();
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mapOverlays.add(overlay);
        this.populate();
    }

}
```

Comment: Do I have to rewrite my code to uses this? Sorry I'm a newbe. I'm not sure where to place this in my code. I know the bottom one is for a second java class. I tried using the first one in my code. I'm getting  a error from "event" on the GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) event.getX(),(int) event.getY()); line of code.

Comment: I'm sorry bro... I can't seem to get this to work for me. I appreciate your help!!! But this code ant working with my code. If you feel like it. if you can. write my code out, and insert your code to see if it works. And post it hear so i can see how to do it. It would be appreciated but not necessarily needed.

Comment: I've been burning my head up trying to figure this out. Watching videos, searching all over Google trying to find something that works with this. The code works. I have about 10 store locations running this same code. It all works. I just want a damn pin to mark my store locations on each of there maps. But again, Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: Ok. I've been messing around with this code you gave me. I get it to work. But I'm having another problem. The marker shows up. But it only shows up when you touch the screen, and two where ever you touch the screen is where it will place the marker. Its then stuck at that point in the map... I've changed my code a little as well.